# Need another way to keep track of weight without using an instance variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out another way to keep track of the current weight of a suitcase, at the moment I use an instance variable but I'm only allowed to use 2 which is a list of items in the suitcase and the max weight.

What would be a way to do this? I've tried creating another method but I just can't figure out a way to do it without using an instance variable.

my code for Suitcase.java:

```
ArrayList<Thing> things; // List stores name of object and weight of object
private int weight; // Need to get rid of this
private int maxWeight;

public Suitcase(int weight) {
    this.maxWeight = weight;
    this.weight = 0; // and this?
    this.things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
}

public void addThing(Thing thing) { // Need to modify this as well
    if (weight < this.maxWeight) {
        things.add(thing);
        weight += thing.getWeight();
        if (weight > this.maxWeight) {
            weight -= thing.getWeight();
            things.remove(things.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}

public Thing heaviestThing() {
    if (!things.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++) {

        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void printThings() {
    for (Thing thing : things) {
        System.out.println(thing);
    }
}

public int totalWeight() {
    return this.maxWeight;
}

@Override
public String toString() { // This is where I have problems because I need to keep track of current weight.
    if (things.isEmpty()) {
        return "empty (" + weight + " kg)";
    } else if (things.size() == 1) {
        return things.size() + " thing (" + weight + " kg)";
    } else {
        return things.size() + " things (" + weight + " kg)";
    }
}
```

My code for Thing.java

```
private String name;
private int weight;

public Thing(String name, int weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return this.weight;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name + " (" + weight + " kg)";
}
```

Comment: Are the list of things related to the weight somehow or contains any infos about it or is it completely unrelated ?

Comment: I updated my main post to make it a bit more clear, the list stores a name and the weight of something.

Comment: Ok so if i understand correctly you can get you max weight by looking through you array of things. Just create a method called getMaxWeight. Inside this method loop through you arrayList and look for the maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `int maxWeight`, why not create a method `calculateWeight()`:

```
public int calculateWeight() {
    int weight = 0;
    for (Thing thing : things) {
        weight += thing.getWeight();
    }
    return weight;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to provide homework answers, why not at least make them syntactically correct?